# JPanel to display large amount of text

Tags: java, swing, text, jpanel

I'm currently searching for a method to display an introduction for my program. Every part of the program has it's own instructions that are several lines long. At the end of each line there is `\n\n` for formatting.

It would be cool if the font size could adjust automatically to the panel size and if the text could be centered. I tried `TextLayout` and adding the text to a simple `JLabel` but none of this displays the text correctly.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `JTextArea` with a `JScrollPane`?

Comment: My suggestion would be to learn some dynamic GUI programming.

Comment: I'd suggest using something like a `JLabel` and possibly use text wrapped in HTML instead, or a `JEditorPane`, which would allow you to use HTML for formatting.  If you're really determined, you could look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818489/text-resize-according-to-button-label-size/20820112#20820112) which demonstrates a `JLabel` which will attempt to resize it's font based on the available space...but its a real mess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use HTML formatting in the JLabel text. All you need to do is surround the text with <html> and </html>, set the font size with a <font> element, and replace every \n with <br>.

```
String formatted = text.replace("\n", "<br>");
formatted = "<html><font size='9'>" + formatted + "</font></html>";
JLabel label = new JLabel(formatted);
```

See [How to Use HTML in Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Josh M, you should try using a [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) with a JScrollPane. Alternatively, if you do not expect too much GUI manipulation by the user, you could manually format the text using basic stuff like [newlines ('\n')](http://www.coderanch.com/t/579851/java/java/actual-character-Java) and [tabs('\t')](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/53052-what-does-n-and-t-mean).

Answer (score 0):

You can give a columns count to your `JTextField`  like this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField("I Have a Big Text and I want show it now!", 40);
```

40 is the column index which means the text has more columns for showing data in default now.

Another way you could do this is to use **JTextArea**