# How can I scale font size to automatically accommodate a static JTextField size?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm making a Matrix calculator in Java using a two-dimensional array of JTextFields on a JPanel to input a given Matrix. Since the panel that this matrix is placed on has a fixed size, I want to scale down the text size to accommodate how long the number is as it's being typed in.

For example:
If it's one digit long, font size = 18. If it's two digits long, font size = 14. Etc. 
I want this to dynamically occur as the user is entering the text, and I want repainting to occur everytime the user interacts with the JTextField, not only after the user presses "enter". This is because the field is transparent and currently looks sloppy (numbers overlapping) until the user presses enter.

What's the most straightforward and reliable way to do this? Here's my current code if it helps anyone answer my question:

```
public class MatrixPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
  float[][] matrice = new float[3][3];
  JTextField[][] parameter = new JTextField[3][3];
  Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 40);


public MatrixPanel(String title)
{
  setLayout(null);
  setOpaque(false);

for (int width = 0; width < 3; width++){
  for (int height = 0; height < 3; height++){
    matrice[width][height] = 0;
    parameter[width][height] = new JTextField();
    parameter[width][height].setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    parameter[width][height].setFont(font);
    parameter[width][height].setText("0");
    parameter[width][height].setLocation((50*width), (50*height));
    parameter[width][height].setSize(50,50);
    parameter[width][height].setOpaque(false);
    parameter[width][height].setBorder(null);
    parameter[width][height].addActionListener(this);
    add(parameter[width][height]);
  }

setSize(150,150);
 }
}
```

Comment: You might like to take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818489/text-resize-according-to-button-label-size/20820112#20820112) - avoid null layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion in modern GUIs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to scale down the text size to accommodate how long the number
>   is as it's being typed in.

Take a look to [How to Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) to achieve your goal.

#### Some useful tips:

- About `setSize(150,150)` and `setLocation((50*width), (50*height))`: please have a look to this topic [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) (yes we should). Components size and location should be handled by layout managers.
- You may want to try [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) to place the text fields in a grid and forget about the fixed size/location. See [How to Use GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) and [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) tutorials for a better understanding on this subject.
- If you want to input floats (or doubles) in your matrix then maybe formatted text fields or spinners are a better choice than plain text fields. Take a look to [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and [How to Use Spinners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html) tutorials.